# ActiveRecord query using multiple conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a employee data base that captures all employees for all companies the companies are referenced by a `company_id`

I want to do something like this

```
sql = "SELECT race, `foreign`, id_number, company_id, COUNT(*) FROM `employees` WHERE company_id = 52 AND race = `African` AND `foreign` = 1 GROUP BY id_number;"
temp_arr = []
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql).each {|int| temp_arr << int }
```

Like this

```
employee_ids = Employees.where(company_id: company_id and race: 'African' and foreign: 1).pluck(:id_number)
```

I keep getting the following error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'African' in 'where clause':
```

And have been reading the [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) and cant seem to find what i am looking for. sorry i have never done such a query before its probably formatted wrong or something

Comment: replace `and` with `,` so it looks like `employee_ids = Employees.where(company_id: company_id, race: 'African', foreign: 1).pluck(:id_number)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to replace 'and' with ','
Try as follow;

```
employee_ids = Employees.where(company_id: company_id, race: 'African',  foreign: 1).pluck(:id_number)
```